# Two PHP echoes in one .php file. Can I isolate them?

Tags: php, web

This is my first time creating a website and I want to have the registration and the login form on one page. Every time I try to register it echoes the data to login and basically the process stops. If I use register independently, it works just fine. Since I am using bootstrap, my whole code is in one big  (but register/login are clearly separated). Is there any way two instruct PHP only echo in/from the segment I work in?

```
<!-- Form Code Start -->
<div id='fg_membersite' class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <form id='register' class="form-horizontal"  action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
                <fieldset >
                    <legend>Register</legend>

                    <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

                    <div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>
                    <input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />

                    <div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
                    <div class='container'>
                        <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
                        <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
                        <span id='register_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='container'>
                        <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
                        <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
                        <span id='register_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='container'>
                        <label for='username' >UserName*:</label><br/>
                        <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
                        <span id='register_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='container' style='height:80px;'>
                        <label for='password' >Password*:</label><br/>
                        <div class='pwdwidgetdiv' id='thepwddiv' ></div>
                        <noscript>
                            <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
                        </noscript>
                        <div id='register_password_errorloc' class='error' style='clear:both'></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='container'>
                        <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <form id='login' class="form-horizontal" action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
                <fieldset >
                    <legend>Login</legend>

                    <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

                    <div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>

                    <div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
                    <div class='container'>
                        <label for='username' >UserName*:</label><br/>
                        <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
                        <span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='container'>
                        <label for='password' >Password*:</label><br/>
                        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /><br/>
                        <span id='login_password_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class='container'>
                        <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
                    </div>
                    <div class='short_explanation'><a href='reset-pwd-req.php'>Forgot Password?</a></div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How will we solve your problem without relevant code provided?

Comment: Yes its possible, what do you have so far?

Comment: hellooo code.... code..... Where are you?

Comment: eaten by the codemonster ò.Ó

Comment: Which framework are you using? CakePHP? Drupal? Wordpress? Something else?  Also, why is your code all in one big file? I don't understand how "using bootstrap" means all your code needs to be in big file. At least I'm assuming "file" is the word that came after "whole code is in one big".

Comment: that word was eaten by the codemonster too, even if its not code ò.Ó

Comment: I am not using any framework and my code isn't all in one big file, just the registration/login form

Comment: @user2315641 this is just the presentation markup, not the actual code that handles the submission. We would need to see the whole php file to work out the problem, but my guess is you have copied this from some script designed to use 2 seperate php files, and the code for login is 1st in the file, so that is what is being processed

Answer (score 1):

You can build it like this:

```
<?php if ($someBool): ?>
   <form id="register">
      <!-- more html here -->
   </form>
<? else: ?>
   <form id="login">
      <!-- yet more html here -->
   </form>
<?php endif ?>
```

It's alternative syntax for `if`. See https://www.php.net/alternative_syntax